# Duplicate row X times based on left join number

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a table (Subscriptions)

```
OrderId | Plan value    
   1    |    A 
   2    |    B    
   3    |    C    
   4    |    A
  ...   |   ...
```

I got my left join table (Plan value)

```
Plan Value ID | Value    
   A          |    2
   B          |    4    
   C          |    1
```

My output table has to be:

```
OrderId | Plan value  
   1    |    A 
   1    |    A 
   2    |    B 
   2    |    B  
   2    |    B  
   2    |    B  
   3    |    C     
   4    |    A
   4    |    A
```

I want tu duplicate X times OrderID row based on left join number from "Value" result.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need a numbers table or recursive CTE.  You can generate a numbers table on-the-fly, assuming a table has enough rows:

```
select s.order_id, s.plan_value
from subscriptions s join
     plans p
     on s.plan_value = p.plan_value_id join
     (select row_number() over () as seqnum
      from subscriptions
      limit 100 -- or the maximum
     ) n
     on n.seqnum <= p.value;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How could i create that "recursive CTE table".

There should not be something inside "over ()" ??

Im kinda lost with this point. Thanks

Comment: @rifoltar . . . MySQL accepts `row_number()` with no `order by` (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3664b5fb7e93713858ee3cd0a7d60092).  The ordering is unimportant -- just the generation of the numbers.  You can `order by` something if you like.